# Copy a fixed number of bytes into an std::deque<char>

Tags: c++, std

I'm making a class that buffers some binary data read from `std::cin`; I need some limited
ability to back-track through the stream.
In more detail, when I `read` `n` bytes from the stream, I want to be able to rewind up to
`n` bytes in the stream.

Currently, I append to the buffer by appending individual characters
to a `std::deque`, but I expect that there is a better way to copy
chunks of data from an `std::istream` into a `std::deque`.

Basically is there a way to improve (remove?) the while loop in
the `load` function below?

Currently I have:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<deque>

class BufferedStdIn{
public:

BufferedStdIn(): m_buffer(), m_cursor(0){
}

// copy data out from my internal buffer to the client's array
// format dictated by external interface requirement
void read(char* dest, size_t n){
    load(n)
    std::copy( m_buffer.begin(), m_buffer.begin()+n, dest );
    m_cursor+=n;
}

// Go backwards in the stream; return the number of bytes moved.
// @retval < input arg n indicates that we can't rewind as far as asked for
size_t rewind(size_t n){
    int final_pos=m_cursor-n;
    if( final_pos < 0 ){
        // can't go as far as the client wants, just go back to start of my buffer
        size_t moved=m_cursor;
        m_cursor=0;
        return moved;
    }
    else{ // can do what client wants
        m_cursor=final_pos;
        return n;
    }
}

void load(n){
    m_buffer.erase( m_buffer.begin(), m_buffer.begin()+m_cursor);
    m_cursor=0;
    while( m_buffer.size()<n){
        char c;
        std::cin.get(c);
        m_buffer.push_back(c);
    }
}

// SNIP: other functions that let clients look at m_buffer

std::deque<char> m_buffer;
size_t m_cursor;


}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? how about using a vector or istream as buffer instead?

Comment: I went with `deque` since the process is: push to back, drop from front -- a pattern which I typically associate with deques.  I guess that I could use `vector` and use the fact that `vector<T>::iterator == T*` (in practice), and provide the appropriate iterator (pointer) to a call to `std::cin.get()`.

Comment: If this is your case I would suggest to use a ring buffer. boost has one. in essense it's a vector that wraps around to the beginning once your reach the buffer boundaries. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not more efficient, but shorter:

```
void load(size_t n)
{
    m_buffer.erase( m_buffer.begin(), m_buffer.begin()+m_cursor);
    m_cursor=0;
    if(m_buffer.size() < n)
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin), n - m_buffer.size(), std::back_inserter(m_buffer));
}
```